# Bean:write filter doesn't work

Tags: xss, struts-1

I'm working on an application with Struts 1 and JSP. I have to write XSS protection. I have inputs like this one :

```
<input id="name"  name="name" class="someClass" type="text" 
        value="<bean:write name="personForm" property="name"/>">
```

I read that for protection XSS attack i have to add attribute filter in bean:write and filter should be true. So my code looks like that now

```
<input id="name"  name="name" class="someClass" type="text" 
        value="<bean:write name="personForm" property="name" filter="true"/>">
```

But still I'm able to submit scripts. Do you know why this might happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bean:write` is only for rendering purposes.The value passed to the server side is not get filtered.